# WaitableTimer with variable period

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, timer

I need to setup a waitable timer that executes periodically.

The catch is the following, the period changes every X (let's say 5) periods, depending on the time it took the system to perform tasks during those last those 5 periods.

I tried used an auto-reset waitable timer that it is being set after each iteration (4 out of 5 times with the same interval). However the timing has nothing to do with what I am setting it to be. The relevant code looks like this. (Everything begins with a call to HandleSensor)

```
    float AnalysisClient::GetNewInterval()
    {
        ...
            return newInterval;
    }

    VOID CALLBACK AnalysisClient::TimerFinished(LPVOID lpArg,
        DWORD dwTimerLowValue,
        DWORD dwTimerHighValue)
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER t;
        AnalysisClient* This = (AnalysisClient*)lpArg;
        This->readsensor();

        t.QuadPart = GetNewInterval() * 10000i64;
        SetWaitableTimer(_sensorTimer, &t, 0, TimerFinished, This, TRUE);
    }


    void AnalysisClient::WaitForsensor()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER t;
        t.QuadPart = 0;
        SetWaitableTimer(_sensorTimer, &t, 0, TimerFinished, this, TRUE);

        SleepEx(
            INFINITE,           // Wait forever.
            TRUE);
    }



    void AnalysisClient::readsensor()
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&_sensorCS);
        {
            while (_numsensorSampled >= _capacity) //no more sensors than the capacity size
            {
                UtilsLog("Queue full, not doing more sensor readings", UtilsDebug);
                SleepConditionVariableCS(&_sensorQueueFullCV, &_sensorCS, INFINITE);
            }

            UtilsLog("Read sensor", UtilsDebug);
            void* sensorreading = _fnSamplesensor();
            _numsensorSampled++;
            _localsensorQueue.push(sensorreading);
            _sensorHandler->Sendreading(sensorreading);
        }
        WakeConditionVariable(&_sensorQueueEmptyCV);
        LeaveCriticalSection(&_sensorCS);
    }

    void* AnalysisClient::Handlesensor()
    {
        //Spawn async thread if not already started

        if (!_asyncsensorHandlerStarted)
        {
            _asyncsensorHandlerStarted = true;
            CreateUtilsThread(Asyncreadsensor, this);
        }



        //Free memory from previous invocations
        ...

            void* returnVal = NULL;


        EnterCriticalSection(&_sensorCS);
        {
            while (_localsensorQueue.empty())
                SleepConditionVariableCS(&_sensorQueueEmptyCV, &_sensorCS, INFINITE);

            _lastreading = _localsensorQueue.front();
            _localsensorQueue.pop();
            returnVal = _lastreading;

            _numsensorProcessed++;
        }
        LeaveCriticalSection(&_sensorCS);

        return returnVal;
    }



    DWORD WINAPI AnalysisClient::Asyncreadsensor(void* Param)
    {
        //Create sensor Timer
        _sensorTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
        if (!_sensorTimer)
        {
            UtilsLog("Unable to create sensor waitable timer", UtilsError);
            return 1;
        }

        AnalysisClient* This = (AnalysisClient*)Param;
        This->WaitForsensor();
        return 0;
    }


bool CreateKahawaiThread(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE function, void* instance)
{
   DWORD ThreadID;
   HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL,0,function, instance, 0, &ThreadID);

   if(thread==NULL)
       return false;

   return true;
}
```

The execution log reveals the following execution (the numerical value to the right is the time in millisecond when the message was written to the log. zi adjusted the call to GetNewInterval to always return 1600000i64 so I can discard it as a source of problems. Still the times in between timer calls have nothing to do with. The capacity as can be seen is set to 5.

```
        30621, Read sensor

        30623, Read sensor

        30624, Read sensor

        30625, Read sensor

        30626, Read sensor

        30627, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        30980, Read sensor

        30981, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        30997, Read sensor

        30998, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31007, Read sensor

        31008, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31019, Read sensor

        31020, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31032, Read sensor

        31033, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31040, Read sensor

        31041, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31054, Read sensor

        31055, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31066, Read sensor

        31068, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31080, Read sensor

        31081, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31087, Read sensor

        31088, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31094, Read sensor

        31096, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31111, Read sensor

        31112, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31121, Read sensor

        31123, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31180, Read sensor

        31181, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31194, Read sensor

        31197, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31294, Read sensor

        31295, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31307, Read sensor

        31308, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31316, Read sensor

        31318, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31332, Read sensor

        31333, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31336, Read sensor

        31337, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31343, Read sensor

        31344, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31359, Read sensor

        31360, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31369, Read sensor

        31371, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31384, Read sensor

        31385, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31391, Read sensor

        31392, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings

        31398, Read sensor

        31399, Queue full, not doing more sensor readings
```

What is the error? Is there perhaps a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `WakeConditionVariable(&_sensorQueueEmptyCV); LeaveCriticalSection(&_sensorCS);` be in reserve order?

Comment: Windows is not known for reliable timing... I think I've read somewhere that Windows only grants that a timer does not expire before it is intended to. When your application processes the timer is a completely different story. One thing that might help is to increase the priority of your application (see [SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: I already solved this with a  while loop and a Sleep call instead. It was simpler and worked better.
Truth be told, Surt is right, and I had the order inverted which maybe was part of the problem.

Finally, I agree with Lukas that it is not reliable. I did only want that guarantee though (not expirng before) still, it was not doing that somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
        while (_numsensorSampled >= _capacity) //no more sensors than the capacity size
```

and

```
        _localsensorQueue.push(sensorreading);
        _numsensorSampled++;
```

and

```
        _localsensorQueue.pop();
        returnVal = _lastreading;

        _numsensorProcessed++;
```

But no

```
        --_numsensorSampled;
```

so

```
        while (_numsensorSampled >= _capacity) //no more sensors than the capacity size
```

will be true always when you have reached this number. change it to

```
        while (_numsensorSampled - numsensorProcessed >= _capacity) //no more sensors than the capacity size
```

should also get it working. Also

```
    WakeConditionVariable(&_sensorQueueEmptyCV);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&_sensorCS);
```

looks wrong, maybe should be

```
    LeaveCriticalSection(&_sensorCS);
    WakeConditionVariable(&_sensorQueueEmptyCV);
```

else the woken process *might* go to sleep immediately again as the critical section is still active.

Comment: That is actually right, I have got them inverted. 

In the end I used a sleep call and that surprisingly worked much better and was so much simpler.
--numsensorsampled is somewhere else in the code btw.